# Is there a way to automatically make a copy of a file each time it is updated in Unix?

Tags: unix, filesystems

I have an application that updates some files in Unix server. Since I cannot modify this application, is there any way I can make sure that these files are copied before each update so I can have a history of the changes?
Is there a way/tool in Unix so I can do that?

Comment: What is that application? Is it some server? What kind (and volume) of files? Please **edit your question** to improve and motivate it...

Comment: What's the maximum frequency with which the files change?  Once an year, month, day, hour, minute, second, multiple times per second?  Answer which are appropriate for some time scales are inappropriate for others.

Answer (score 2):

If **on Linux** (specifically) you could use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities (perhaps via [incrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) ...)

Alternatively, you might run periodically (thru some [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entry) a script doing some `make` with your particular `Makefile` (since [GNU `make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) is designed to care about timestamps) managing e.g. backups. Or you could periodically run some [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) command.

However, it smells like you need some [revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (also known as version control system). I strongly recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/); you could use it *before* and *after* running your application (e.g. write some wrapping shell script doing that).

But there is probably no universal solution (e.g. what if the monitored application is keeping a file descriptor opened for a long time, and write the file little by little...). You should explain much more what is happening and what do you want ...

Comment: This is a good answer, but at a level the OP apparently  cannot use.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: why do you believe the OP cannot use that? His request is quite unusual, and he need to dive quite deep in his system to make something that sometimes work.

Comment: We do this for several applications - we use inotify in linux, and /proc monitoring in Solaris. Without futher infomation from the OP - like what OS - we cannot help. @basilestarynkevitch

Comment: I started my answer with "If on Linux (specifically)" .... so of course it won't apply to Solaris